# jquery not working on django

Tags: javascript, jquery, django, twitter-bootstrap-3

jquery does not work on django project I used with bootstrap. please help me

.html

```
    <div class="domains-slider marquee">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">BTC/USD</a><span class="price"> $2,33 CAD</span></li>
      </ul>
    </div>

{% load static %}
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>    
  <script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'js/bootstrap.min.js' %}"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'js/script.js' %}"></script>
 </body>
</html>
```

script.js

```
jQuery(window).load(function() {
  jQuery(".marquee").marquee({
    duration: 10 * jQuery(".marquee").width(),
    duplicated: true,
    pauseOnHover: true
  });
});
```

Comment: which error do you recive?

Comment: 'Not working' isn't a useful description of the problem. What are you expecting to happen? What does happen? Have you checked the console for errors? At first glance it appears you're calling a `marquee()` function, yet none of the libraries you've included have that.

Comment: "ReferenceError: z is not defined" and "TypeError: a.indexOf is not a function" @hansTheFranz,

Comment: So is jQuery not working or are you having problems with your code/bootstrap?

Comment: yes, jQuery code is not running. @Eagllus

Answer (score 1, accepted):

is solved :)

```
{% load static %}
<!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery.marquee@1.5.0/jquery.marquee.min.js"></script>
```